# SpreadSheet- google script - how to find text in string using "findText()" method?

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the fragment of my GS. When I run then it returned error "TypeError: text.findText is not a function".
What mistake I did? thanks..

```
var text = "Martin test x";
Logger.log(text);
var range2 = text.findText("x");
```

I would have expected range value "12" in result.

Comment: You can use indexOf()

Answer (score 1):

It's actually 12.

```
function myfunction() {
  var text = "Martin test x";
   Logger.log(text.indexOf('x'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Cooper, it helped and worked fine. Anyway, what was wrong with "findText()"? it cannot be used for searching position within the string?

Comment: it's not a string method in Javascript [string methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: There is a document.getBody().findText() method.